# How to pull specific data from a Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, discord.js, discord.io

I'm trying to utilize [Fortnite-api](https://github.com/qlaffont/fortnite-api) to create a Discord bot with Node.js. When I use the method included with the Fortnite-api to retrieve user data, I receive a large object, which I've included below. I can use JSON.Stringify() to turn it into a string, but that doesn't really help me access a specific piece of this data. I'd like to be able to retrieve all info under the "solo" group, or "duo" group, etc. and be able to utilize the keys individually under those groups as well.

Ex: soloWins = stats.group.solo.wins (or something equivalent) would return "1"

Any help is appreciated!

```html
{ group:
   { solo:
      { wins: 1,
        top3: 0,
        top5: 0,
        top6: 0,
        top10: 11,
        top12: 0,
        top25: 29,
        'k/d': '0.95',
        'win%': '0.01',
        matches: 122,
        kills: 115,
        timePlayed: '14h 47m',
        killsPerMatch: '0.94',
        killsPerMin: '0.13' },
     duo:
      { wins: 0,
        top3: 0,
        top5: 9,
        top6: 0,
        top10: 0,
        top12: 18,
        top25: 0,
        'k/d': '1.25',
        'win%': '0.00',
        matches: 60,
        kills: 75,
        timePlayed: '7h 11m',
        killsPerMatch: '1.25',
        killsPerMin: '0.17' },
     squad:
      { wins: 1,
        top3: 12,
        top5: 0,
        top6: 16,
        top10: 0,
        top12: 0,
        top25: 0,
        'k/d': '1.43',
        'win%': '0.02',
        matches: 59,
        kills: 83,
        timePlayed: '9h 19m',
        killsPerMatch: '1.41',
        killsPerMin: '0.15' } },
  info:
   { accountId: '6372c32ec81d4a0a9f6e79f0d5edc31a',
     username: 'Mirardes',
     platform: 'pc' },
  lifetimeStats:
   { wins: 2,
     top3s: 12,
     top5s: 9,
     top6s: 16,
     top10s: 11,
     top12s: 18,
     top25s: 29,
     'k/d': '1.14',
     'win%': '0.01',
     matches: 241,
     kills: 273,
     killsPerMin: '0.15',
     timePlayed: '1d 7h 17m' }
   }
 }
```

Comment: `soloWins = stats.group.solo.wins` should work, assuming `stats` is the name of the object..? What happens when you do that?

Comment: Wow. That works. Not sure what I did wrong before... Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming what you are getting from the server is a json string and not actually an object right away. There might be some other way which would be more correct in parsing it more directly, but you could just take the string that you receive from the server and turn it into an object. In that case you have to parse it into an object like this:

```
let soloWins = JSON.parse(requestResponse).group.solo.wins
```

Comment: This works, along with the method CertainPerformance gave. Thanks!